# Play Store gone from my Cyanogenmod 7 Galaxy Ace. How can I get it back?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-ace

Recently, the play store went missing from my apps list. I have tried reinstalling it from the apk file but the apk installation tells me I am out of space. I have deleted all my apps and have 80mb of internal space and it still gives the same error .I have tried older versions and I get the same error. I then went into system/apps and data/apps and data/data and there is nothing left over from the playstore. I have also tried to reinstall all of gapps from recovery but that didn't work either.

I am really stuck and wondering what I can do. I wanted to use clean master to get rid of all the obselete data files but that has the same installation issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried formatting the system partition, and then flashing both CyanogenMod and Gapps package? (notice: reinstalling the system won't factory reset your phone, you will continue where you left off)

Comment: Yeah, I formatted and reflashed a day after asking. (which is why i never responded, i lost this page.) It all works fine now, I just had to reinstall all my apps.

Answer (score 0):

Format the system Partition and reflash Cyanogenmod and Gapps in recovery. Unfortunately you will have to reinstall all apps (even ones on the SD card).

Note: Sometimes, bizarrely, it can wipe part of a SD card. I lost photos and videos and also appdata (which was ext4) but all my downloads and recovery zips remained. Not sure if that it a problem with the OS, my phone or the recovery system I use. Just thought I would mention it as a warning, just in case.